# javascript detection of two equal parameter

Tags: javascript, numbers, equals, auto-increment

i have a function that have 2 equal numbers in it(for example 21), these numbers are generated automatically and unknown(increment from 1),
how can i relate all equal numbers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bt_Form_ReplyForm_21").click(function(){
        $("#box_21").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I tried solve this problem with foreach, is this solution is correct?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors#Substring_value_attribute_selectors

Comment: Where are the numbers being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [*starts with* selector `...^⁼...`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

On click grab the number of the id of the clicked element and use it in the selector for the `.slideToggle()` call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^="bt_Form_ReplyForm_"]').click(function() {
    var id = this.id.split("_").pop();
    $("#box_" + id).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setRandomId();

  $('[id^="bt_Form_ReplyForm_"]').click(function() {
    var id = this.id.split("_").pop();
    $("#box_" + id).slideToggle();
  });
});

function setRandomId() {
  var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $("button").attr("id", "bt_Form_ReplyForm_" + id);
  $("div").attr("id", "box_" + id)
          .text("Slide - " + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button type="button" id="bt_Form_ReplyForm_21">Click me...</button>
</form>

<div id="box_21">Slide - 21</div>
```